Current regulator and HPF design
I'm creating this new post to have more inputs and suggestions for the schematic I designed.
My requirement is current source shall generate 4 mA and bias the ICP sensor and the output of the sensor shall be given to HPF to remove DC offset. I would like to know if the wiring schema of current source and HPF design will work. I'm attaching the schematics. Could anyone enlighten me about what is going wrong in the circuit?


Have you tried to simulate it?

Nope.. I don't have any simulation software.

This is a reminder from your last question (which I answered); you should link the data sheet for the sensor and, in addition, link the data sheets of the other chips.  You should also precisely state what is happening in the circuit above (TP11?) that doesn't meet your expectations. What is the ICP sensor? Is it marked on your schematic somewhere? Add the data sheet links within your post.

sensor datasheet link: https://www.pcb.com/products?m=j352c65
the BNC conn1 is where the sensor shall be connected. once the circuit is powered ON, it shall generate 4mA constant current to excite the sensor and the sensor output of 100mV shall be superimposed on 12.5V DC signal. If I measure the voltage output at TP11 it shows 0V

Please get one. There are several free alternatives, Falstad and LTspuce springs to mind.

@priya if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

There is a major error in the way you have connected the LM334 current regulator: -

The negative terminal of the LM334 feeds to the load (your sensor) but, you have it connected to ground. It should be like this: -

I'd also recheck the resistor values you have for R1 and R33 in case you are out by some factor. I believe that 17.5 Ω results in around 3 mA flowing into the sensor.

I hope 16 ohm resistor will give me 4mA current to excite the sensor

@priya Hope != engineering. Calculate, simulate and test.
